# "Toast" is showing error. i run the code without it and it worked just fine but i need it in order to see my button working or not

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working in a Bluetooth chat app and I just finished the interface in order to test my buttons I need to use Toast and it is showing error. I run the code without it and it runs fine

```
@Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.menu_search_devices:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "clicked searched devices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_enable_bluetooth:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "clicked Enable Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();**here the problem**
                    return true;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting here.

Comment: the problem solved i forgot writing writing content = this;